# Need of private modifier in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, encapsulation, access-modifiers

I am new to C#.
This makes me confusing.If we building some project.Why we have private data members.Although everything is accessed by us according to our requirement.Nobody have access to our code.Then what is the need of private modifiers in C#

Comment: Imagine you have a collection that has `Add` and `Remove` methods and you keep a private variable for `Count`. Now you know it's safe for you to modify the `Count` within your methods, but if it were ever modified outside those methods it would likely not be accurate. Public and private access modifiers allow you to identify what are safe operations for consumers of your class and what can only be known to be safe within your implementation.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been asked and answered here. This clearly belongs to programmer SE and in fact has been asked there. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

Answer (score 2):

Because one of the cornerstones in `Object Oriented Programming` is `encapsulation`. This mean you hide implementation details not concerned by any outside logic.

By dividing logic into several private methods instead of one big public method, you follow the pattern `Single Responsible Patterns` where you get robust code which is easier to maintain.

Please start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx) to understand the basics in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

The [Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables) provides you the necessary details about why should we use private for fields. We declare private for the fields to stop processing it functionalities in other classes. Although it could be accessed using public methods or properties.

Comment: Thankx alot.now i understand it properly

Comment: @ChamanjitKaur You are Welcome. Mark as answer if you were fulfilled with the information.